# Commerce Server 2009 API - Get All Profiles

Tags: e-commerce, microsoft-commerce-server

Is there a way, using the CS2009 API, to get all profiles?  I have trying to migrate to the CS2009 API, and I need to be able to get all profiles from a custom profile.

It looks like with using "CommerceQuery", you are required to pass a field that is either a "primary", "unique", or "join".  This limits my ability to get all profiles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not an API on CS 2099 to get all profiles... you can use CS 2007 core API to search on the profile system
http://ecommerceondotnet.blogspot.it/2009/12/search-on-profile-system.html
... or even better make a sql query on your database..

Answer (score 0):

I would concur with Stelio. I would also recommend writing your own sequence component to do this using custom SQL, it will give you more control over your query and performance. I would not recommend using the API. Checkout the proile API code with .NET reflector, or take a gander at the stored procedures in the _profiles database and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Please do not include invitations to contact you in your posts.